# Increment time by 2 seconds every 10th row

Tags: time, increment

I have been asked to create time slots by 2 second intervals every 10th row. I managed to make changes from a date formula but it only increments by 1 second. I have tried editing the formula but still get 1 second increments instead of 2.
I am using the formula: =TIME(HOUR($C1),MINUTE($C$1),SECOND($C$1)+INT((ROW()-1)/11)) where C1 is the start time.

Any answers very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I eventually sorted it out with: =TIME(HOUR($C$1),MINUTE($C$1),SECOND($C$1)+INT((ROW()-1)/11))*2